# Как убрать скролл ко второму блоку на сайте?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

Здравствуйте!
Разрабатываю сайт, возникла проблема: при входе на главную страницу сайт автоматически скроллится ко второму блоку. Искал решение везде: в CSS, JS, jQuery, но так и не нашел решения.

Вот ссылка на сайт: [atobtransfer.com](http://atobtransfer.com).

P.S. в Мозилле, Опере и Хроме работает по-разному:

- В Хроме кидает на второй блок, потом возвращает на первый;
- В Опере кидает на второй блок, на нем и остается;
- В Мозилле проблем нет, все работает отлично.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: У вас так называемый "Quirks mode", укажите точно doctype

Comment: добавил <!DOCTYPE html>, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Меняем стили на следующие

```
#banner .bg-mask {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 90px);
    background: rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.5);
    /* padding: 30vh 0; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

то есть убираем оттуда padding. Скорее всего дело именно в нем

Comment: Не помогает(( скорее всего, дело в iframe. Но все равно, спасибо за ответ)